# Filter and delete rows where cells contain 3,115148E+28

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to delete rows. I have in cells 3,115148E+28.

I tried this code. What can I write in Criteria1?

I tried Criteria1 with "0000000" or with 3.11.

```vb
Sub delete()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
    ws.Activate
        
    ws.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*E+*"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ws.Range("A2:A100000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        
    On Error Resume Next
    ws.ShowAllData
    On Error GoTo 0
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a surprisingly tricky problem.  It seems that a lot depends on the number format of the cells containing the number you wish to use to delete rows.  The only way I could get this to work was to change Column A to scientific notation (and even then it had to be specifically 6 decimal places) and then back to General afterwards – assuming that’s what the original format was.  You can return the format of Column A to whatever you want.

I’m sure there must be a simpler solution than this, and I’ll happily delete this answer if a better one comes along.

```
Option Explicit
Sub DeleteMyNumber()
Dim LR As Long

Sheet1.Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "0.000000E+00"
Sheet1.Range("A:A").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="3.115148E+28"
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

If LR = 1 Then
  MsgBox "No records selected"
  GoTo GetOut
   Else
   Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
End If

GetOut:
Sheet1.ShowAllData
Sheet1.Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "General"

End Sub
```